# Use of "the" with "Tian'anmen Square"

Tags: articles, definite-article

I am unsure of the use of the definite article "the" in the following case:

> During the demonstrations in **the** Tian'anmen Square...

Should I use the article or not?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You need to complete your sentence (as written it is not one). If you are using "Tian'anmen Square" as a modifier, the following noun will determine the need for an article.

Comment: @arsa Welcome to ELL. Use the [edit](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/101848/edit) link below your question to include the complete sentence in which the phrase appears. Please visit our and [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages to learn how to write a useful question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit complicated and probably mostly idiomatic.  In this case, since Tiananmen Square is primarily a named place, the answer to your question is no -- Tiananmen Square does not use the "the." (See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59271/why-there-is-the-before-some-names-but-not-others)

"During the demonstrations in Tian'anmen Square..."